# input field css changed when using typeahead.js

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I'm trying to create simple entrance page like this [bootstrap4 example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/floating-labels/).

I copied the entire [css file](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/floating-labels/floating-labels.css) from the example above (and the html source as well).

Now I'm trying to combine it with typeahead: I want to replace the email input field with "Country Name" using typeahead as explained [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#the-basics).
I want my input fields to look like:
[image]

But the typeahead makes it looks like:

[image]

here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ItayB/v03Lh6L9/4/).

**HTML:**
    
      
        
        Floating labels</h1>-->

```
  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" id="cName" class="form-control" placeholder="Country Name" required autofocus>
    <label for="cName">Country Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="options-menu form-label-group"></div>
  <div class="form-label-group">
    <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg" style="font-size: 100%;">
      <option selected>Pick one</option>
      <option value="1">Strategy 1</option>
      <option value="2">Strategy 2</option>
      <option value="3">Strategy 3</option>
      <option value="3">Strategy 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Next</button>
  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted text-center">&copy; 2018 R&D</p>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
    :root {
    --input-padding-x: .75rem;
    --input-padding-y: .75rem;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 420px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-label-group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form-label-group > input,
.form-label-group > label {
    padding: var(--input-padding-y) var(--input-padding-x);
}

.form-label-group > label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0; /* Override default `<label>` margin */
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.form-label-group input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
    padding-top: calc(var(--input-padding-y) + var(--input-padding-y) * (2 / 3));
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
    padding-top: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #777;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look at your Fiddle it seems that when you integrated the typehead with Bootstrap it caused either the font size/type to change or the input field height changed (not 100% sure) In either case if you look at your CSS the first entry is:

```
:root {
    --input-padding-x: .75rem;
    --input-padding-y: .75rem;
}
```

This sets a padding height and padding width of `.75rem` which is being used for the input field where you see it showing incorrectly:

```
.form-label-group > input,
.form-label-group > label {
    padding: var(--input-padding-y) var(--input-padding-x);
}
```

There are a lot of ways to fix this and I am not sure what would work best in your case. It may be a matter of adjusting the `--input-padding-x` and `--input-padding-y` to a size that will fit better for your form elements or perhaps you need to just change the padding for the `.form-label-group > input` and `.form-label-group > label` classes to something hard coded instead. Hope that helps or at least gets you pointed in the right direct.

Comment: not sure if it has something with the current css definitions. If I try to remove the entire css code, after the alert the input field size changed as well